# Display taxonomy term slugs

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, slug, terms

I'm looking to display a slug list of the taxonomy term for the current post within the loop.

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpsc_product_category' ); if ( !empty( $terms ) ){ $term = array_shift( $terms ); echo $term->slug; } ?>
```

The function I have currently works, although it's only displaying the slug of the first taxonomy term, and not all of them.

e.g. One post is assigned to multiple `wpsc_product_category`, but only the first term is being display on the front-end, and not a list of all of them.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is completely wrong. [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) should not be used

> **array_shift()** shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be touched.

You should have a look at the correct use of [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) in the codex.

I would just like to point out, I usually make use of [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) as it gives a lot of flexibility, and it also works with custom taxonomies. Here is a example from the codex

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'wpsc_product_category';

// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
// separator between links
$separator = ', ';

if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms;
}
?>
```